# How to convert String into Date in java?

Tags: java, string, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

I want to convert String into Date format..How to do it?
Normal way i can do it like for  "dd-MM-yyyy"..
But i want to convert following Strings

String sdate= "Jun 7, 2012 5:40:00 PM ";
String edate ="Jun 28, 2012 5:40:00 PM ";

How to do it?
Please help!

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String edate ="Jun 28, 2012 5:40:00 PM ";
String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
String strDateNew = sdf.format(edate);
```

Comment: that didnt work for me.. :(
but got other solution.. :)

Comment: @sumit ok.good.if my solution didnt work,can send me the link of other one.i want to know

Answer (score 0):

This is the API you should be looking into [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I was looking for AM,PM thing also..ur link helped me alot ..thnkz :)